# xslt navigation apply template to child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XMl document like this

```
<Page ID="28" AreaID="1" MenuText="Om IAI" Href="Default.aspx?ID=28" FriendlyHref="/da-dk/om-iai.aspx" Allowclick="True" Hidden="False" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="1" RelativeLevel="1" Sort="1" LastInLevel="False" InPath="True" ChildCount="2" class="L1_Active" Active="True" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True">
    <Page ID="29" AreaID="1" MenuText="Underside med langt navn" Href="Default.aspx?ID=29" FriendlyHref="/da-dk/om-iai/underside-med-langt-navn.aspx" Allowclick="True" Hidden="False" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="1" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L2" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
    <Page ID="30" AreaID="1" MenuText="SubPage 2" Href="Default.aspx?ID=30" FriendlyHref="/da-dk/om-iai/subpage-2.aspx" Allowclick="True" Hidden="False" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="2" LastInLevel="True" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L2" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
  </Page>
```

And I want a out like this from above xml

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <a>level 1</a>
       <nav>
          <div><ul><li><a>level 2</a></li></ul></div>
          <div><ul><li><a>level 2</a></li></ul></div>
       </nav>
   </li>
</ul>
```

My xslt template look like this

```
<xsl:template match="//Page">
        <xsl:param name="depth"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <li>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:if test="@ChildCount > 0">dropdown </xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@ChildCount > 0">
            <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@FriendlyHref" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                  <xsl:text>dropdown-toggle</xsl:text>             
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="data-toggle">
                    <xsl:text>dropdown</xsl:text>   
                </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                  </a>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <a>
                      <xsl:attribute name="href">
                          <xsl:value-of select="@FriendlyHref" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                      </xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                  </a>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="count(Page)">
          <nav class="dropdown-menu col-sm-12">
            <xsl:call-template name="MegaMenu">
                <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth+1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </nav>   
        </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
```

Basically i am unsure on how to wrap each level 2 item in div and ul element and i am also looking for a recursive method so it can also handle level 3 under level 2. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XSLT, you call a named template called `MegaMenu`, which is not shown elsewhere. I am not sure what this is meant to be doing, but I think to solve your current issue you could use an `xsl:for-each` of the child Pages, where you create the `div` tag, and then recursively call the "Page" template.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Page">
        <xsl:param name="depth" select="1"/>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="{@FriendlyHref}">
                    <xsl:text>Level </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$depth" />
                    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </a>
                <xsl:if test="Page">
                    <nav>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Page">
                            <div>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth + 1" />
                                </xsl:apply-templates>
                            </div>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </nav>
                </xsl:if>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I resolved my problem yesterday by exactly the same way you suggested :)